# MsAccess Vba SQL Quotes (single / double)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a sql that works fine.  In the where-clause I' am using a recordset as parameter.

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database

Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset

Dim strsql As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb

Set rsData = dbs.OpenRecordset("Qry_GetEntPersoon")
sqltext = "SELECT KISS_tblENTITEITEN.EntiteitVatting FROM KISS_tblENTITEITEN WHERE ((KISS_tblENTITEITEN.EntiteitVatting)= '" & rsData!KISSEntiteitVatting & "');"

Set qrydeftemp = dbs.CreateQueryDef("xxtempxx", sqltext)
```

I have a problem when there are quotes in the name, then I get a syntax error.
I don't know how to change the single quotes to double quotes in de sql to correct the syntax error.

[image]

Comment: `replace(rsData!KISSEntiteitVatting,"'","''")`

Comment: It's not a space, it's 2 single quotes.